# Create Setup, which installs Microsoft SQL Server 2005, if not installed (with Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, installation, setup-project

I want to create a setup which requires Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and .NET Framework 3.5. If this software isn't installed, the Setup should offer the user to install them now.

Comment: The full version of SQL server 2005 would require that they buy a license.  Do you maybe mean the express edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can include either of the two in the installation package itself.

However, you can tell the setup app to check if the .Net Framework and SQL Server 2005 Express Edition are installed. If they are not, it will download and install them and then continue with the installation of you application. Of course, that does require an Internet connection.

These options are available when you right-click on your setup project, select Properties, and then click on the Prerequisites button.

Note that like Paddy said, SQL Server 2005 is a different story.

Comment: Is it possible to install the .NET Framework and the SQL Server 2005 Express automatically, when not installed. At the moment there are only 3 new directories with the setups for the required software.

Comment: By automatically, do you mean without user interaction, silently? The above method is automatic in the sense that it does the checking and downloading and installing for you, but you do have to click a couple of times. Sorry, but I don't understand the second part about the directories.

Comment: No, i don't want a silent installation.. I built the setup-project. Now in the bin directory is the setup.exe, a msi-file and 3 directories (DotNetFX35, SqlExpress, WindowsInstaller3_1). I started the setup on a computer without SqlExpress but the setup didn't install the Sql Express.

Comment: That's odd. I've made dozens of Setup projects the way I described above and nothing even remotely similar ever happened. All I get is Setup.exe and my_app_name.msi. No subdirectories at all.

Comment: Ok, maybe I know why. I selected the checkbox "Install required components from same path like application" (Or something like that. My Visual Studio is german). I want to avoid, the user needs internet connectivity if he wants to install the application. I Think that's the reason why there are this directories with the setups for the components.

Comment: That sure sounds like it could be the problem. If you mean 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, I believe that again you have to have an Internet connection. There might be another way to do it, but I was unable to find out how. I've experimented with bundling everything in a single file (SQLSEE 2005, .Net framework, app) using the NSIS installer, and I did eventually succeed in making it work, but it was not easy and I never tried it on anything but my test machine.

Answer (score 1):

As others said before, SQL Server 2005 is a different ballgame, however if it's SQL Server 2005 Express that you want, it's straightforward. 
This sample from [www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com) might help:

[.NET Installer that Automatically Installs SQL 2005 Express](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/NET_Installer_With_SQLEXP.aspx)